# Inititalze vector of custom class?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have the following the class:

```
//Rectangle.h
#include "Point.h"
class Rectangle{

public: 
    Rectangle(); 

    void setWidth(int); 
    void setHeight(int);

    int getWidth(); 
    int getHeight(); 

    void draw(Point); 

private: 
    int m_width; 
    int m_height; 

}; 

//Rectangle.cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <GL/Gl.h>
#include <GL/Glu.h>
#include <GL/Glut.h>

#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Point.h"

//constructor
Rectangle::Rectangle(){

}

int Rectangle::getHeight(){
    return m_height; 
}

int Rectangle::getWidth(){
    return m_width; 
}

void Rectangle::setHeight(int a_height){
    m_height = a_height; 
}

void Rectangle::setWidth(int a_width){
    m_width = a_width; 
}

void Rectangle::draw(Point center){

    int pointWidth = m_width / 2; 
    int pointHeight = m_height / 2; 

    std::cout << "drawing rectangle at" << center.getX() << ", " << center.getY() << std::endl; 
    glColor3f(1, 1, 0); 

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); 

    glVertex2i( center.getX() - pointWidth, center.getY() - pointHeight ); 
    glVertex2i( center.getX() + pointWidth, center.getY() - pointHeight ); 
    glVertex2i( center.getX() + pointWidth, center.getY() + pointHeight ); 
    glVertex2i( center.getX() - pointWidth, center.getY() + pointHeight ); 

    glEnd(); 
}
```

And then I have the following in main.cpp. The problem is with the line `vector<Rectangle> rectangles;` I get the following error:

> std::vector : Rectangle is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>   
#include <string>
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Point.h"
#include "Pentagon.h"
#include "Star.h"
#include "StringManip.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <GL/Gl.h>
#include <GL/Glu.h>
#include <GL/Glut.h>

using namespace std;

// Function prototypes for callbacks
void myDisplay(void);
void myInit();

void openFile(string); 

Point point; 
vector<Point> points; 
vector<Rectangle> rectangles; 
vector<Pentagon> pentagons; 
vector<Star> stars;
```

I'm at a loss for what's up. I think I've done my class correctly. If anyone could tell me what's wrong, I'd appreciate it.

Here's Point.h and Point.cpp

```
//Point.h
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class Point {

public:

    //default constructor
    Point () {
        m_xCoord = 0;
        m_yCoord = 0;
    }

    //set x and y
    void setX(int a_x); 
    void setY(int a_y); 

    //get x and y
    int getX(); 
    int getY(); 

    //change x and y by a specified value. 
    void changeX(int a_x); 
    void changeY(int a_y); 

private: 
    int m_xCoord;
    int m_yCoord;
};


#endif

//Point.cpp
#include "Point.h"

void Point::setX(int a_x){
    m_xCoord = a_x; 
}

void Point::setY(int a_y){
    m_yCoord = a_y; 
}

int Point::getX(){
    return m_xCoord; 
}

int Point::getY(){
    return m_yCoord; 
}

void Point::changeX(int a_x){
    m_xCoord += a_x; 

    if(m_xCoord < 0){
        m_xCoord = 0; 
    }
}

void Point::changeY(int a_y){
    m_yCoord += a_y; 

    if(m_yCoord < 0){
        m_yCoord = 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show `Point.h` (You are including it twice by the way, which is unnecessary).

Comment: Looks like you actually get something else for `Rectangle` than your class. You'd get that error e.g. if `Rectangle` was a template.

Comment: I have a minimal testcase with `Point.h` and `Rectangle.h` that works. Do you include `Rectangle.h` somewhere else? It missing the include guard. What's your compiler?

Comment: You're not posting real code. Please make some effort to produce a minimal example that exhibits your problem. The posted code doesn't contain the error.

Comment: I'm using Visual C++ 2010. But I'm pretty sure I solved my problem either way. I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556346/reserved-class-name-visual-c after I tried to remake the class. So I just called the class Rect and now my program compiles and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including `<Windows.h>`, which will pollute the global namespace with many, many declarations, including a function called [`Rectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that clashes with your class.

If you actually need the Windows API, your best option is probably to put all your stuff inside a namespace.

Comment: How on earth is a normal programmer to know this? Who is so wicked and puts something with a name like `Rectangle` in the global namespace?